# Python: How split a string keyspace (id) for parallel processing of data in a mongoDB

Tags: python, algorithm, parallel-processing

**Intro**

I have a mongo cluster with several million documents in it. Each document have a string id that looks like this:

```
00072312e0761c6554c3606b50a21119773f2f7d
```

And I have a way of retrieving from mongo the first and last key

Max id:

```
find().sort( { _id : -1 } ).limit(1).next()._id
```

Min id:

```
find().sort( { _id : 1 } ).limit(1).next()._id
```

**The problem**

Now I want to launch a fixed number of threads working on the data, and I want to use the index by id to split the entire dataset evenly among the threads, for example:

Dataset ids (orderer):

```
key1
key2
key3
key4
```

With this small example I want to be able to launch 2 threads, one of the threads to process starting from key2 (inclusive) and ending on key3, and the other thread starting from key3 and ending on key4.

**The question**

How can I calculate the value of key3 (the middle string?) for a given max and min key values like this ones?

```
min key: 000001177ab8e0cd68586e93664911dbd549ab01
max key: 000724471401ce132f8be806b597cbd6ee9b070e
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think what you wanted to ask here was: "If I have two strings sorted in order, how do I find the middle or approximate middle?" For example, the middle string between "AAAAA" and "CCCCCC" could be approximated as the string "B".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to estimate the number of different values in the space.  In this case, it looks like the ID is a hex string, so you should transform them to ints first:

```
my_min_key = int('mylowkey', 16)
my_max_key = int('myhighkey', 16)
```

Then, you can know approximately how many items there are in the space, and that will let you, by dividing by the number of available "processors", how many keys will be asigned to a processor.

```
keys_for_each_processor = (my_max_key - my_min_key) / my_number_of_processors
```

After that, calculate the different lower bounds of each section and transform it back to a hex string so that it matches your keyspace - then you could use a greater than operator to divide the queries.

```
key_bounds = dict()

for proc_num in xrange(0, number_of_processors):
    key_bounds[proc_num] = add_padding(format(my_min_key + proc_num * keys_for_each_processor))
```

Where `add_padding` would add the number of necessary leading zeroes to the string so that it will be ordered lexicographically in the proper way for your keyspace (I'm assuming that's what you need).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this was my first approach to the problem. But then a question arises about the difference between a string comparison and a long comparison. I can safely determine the total number of different keys that exists between min and man divide it by the number of threads I want to execute at any given time and give a "chunk" of the spatial key partition to process to each thread. Then each thread receives a min key value (to execute the greater than operation) and an upper bound were the assigned key space ends, but feels like there something else I'm missing in the picture.Thanks for reading!

Comment: I think this is why you would add the padding to the string - so you add as many zeroes as you need to the front.  That would make `1117` be like `00001117`, ordered before `00100456`, which would make sense.  If you just converted it to a string as `1117`, it would work differently, assuming lexicographical ordering.

Comment: If those IDs are base-16 encoded strings, then they are not numbers and should not be interpreted as numbers (would you interpret this base-256 encoded string as a number: "Tequila!"). If the IDs are base-16 encoded UUIDs, then the leading 0's on both the min and max bounds are a "smell" and indicate that something is not right with the keys. The maximum keys should start a succession of "F"'s –